# Strong markov property: a.s finite hitting time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $ (X_n)_n $ be an irreducible Markov chain on a countable set E.  We call $ T_x^k $ the kth hitting time on x, such that $ T_x^1 = inf\{ n \geq 1, X_n = x \} $ and $ T_x^k = inf\{ n \geq T_x^k + 1 , X_n = x\} $

With the strong markov property (the version with conditional expectation would be appreciated)  show that

$ \mathbb{P}_{x_0} (T_x^k < \infty) = 1 $  , $ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*  \forall x, x_0 \in E $

that

$ \mathbb{P}_x ( T_y^{k+1} - T_y^k = m)  = \mathbb{P}_y ( T_y = m)  $

And that  $ T_y^{k+1} - T_y^k $ is an i. i.d sequence.

I would be grateful for any help as i'm not very familiar with this property as of now and that would help me understand how it works a little better.

As a side note, i got more inspiration for proving that :

$ \forall x ≠ y \in E, \mathbb{E}_x [N_y] = \mathbb{P}_x (T_y^1 < \infty)  \mathbb{E}_y [N_y]  $

With $ N_y$ the total number of visits to y.

As that ressembles more the formula of the property but i'm also not entirely sure here.

My take on this :

$ \mathbb{E}_x [ N_y ]  $

$ =  \mathbb{E} [ [ \mathbb{E}_x [ \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{1}_{X_n = y} | \mathcal{F}_{T_y}^X ] ]  $

$ =  \mathbb{E} [ \mathbb{E}_x [ \mathbb{1}_{ T_y < \infty} \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{1}_{X_{T_y +n }= y} | \mathcal{F}_{T_y}^X ] ] $

$ = \mathbb{E} [ \mathbb{1}_{T_y < \infty} \mathbb{E}_{X_{T_y}} [ \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{1}_{X_n = y } ] ] $

$ = \mathbb{P} (T_y < \infty)  \mathbb{E}_y [N_y] $   ?